# Programatically Setting environment variable for the machine in java

Tags: java, environment-variables

I would like to programatically add a folder for environment variable path for the machine in Java code.

(similar to using framework method SetEnvironmentVariable in C# [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable Method (String, String, EnvironmentVariableTarget)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

I would like to know if java provides this facility or if there are java libraries which provide this.

Regards

Rajagopal

Comment: Did you see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 ?